# dreamweaver cs6 show where style is used

Tags: css, dreamweaver

I'm using Dreamweaver CS6 to maintain a small web site of 23 pages.  I'd like to find out if a particular CSS style, like ".anchor" is used at all, and if so, which pages use it.  I can't seem to find this out from a web search.
Thanks for looking at this.
Phil

Comment: Edit...Find and Replace...Find in... And make sure you're searching the source code.

Comment: I suggest you to use "Brackets" as an HTML/CSS editor. It is made with js,html and css and by Apple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Search and Replace to accomplish that.

[image: Search and Replace]